# Loading modified schema to Spark

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark

I have a Postgres database with raw data and I want to analyze it with Spark.
However, I don't need all columns to do the manipulations.

For example, I have the following columns:

- `name`
- `surname`
- `age`

And I want to operate only on `name` and `age`. How to achieve that in Java and Spark?

Comment: Why don't you just select `name` and `age` so that the dataframe only contains those columns?

Comment: Is it possible to do so? I have found only a method for reading by a table:
    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read()
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
      .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
      .option("user", "username")
      .option("password", "password")
      .load();

Comment: the `load` method will return a `DataFrame`, lets call it `df`. Then, if you apply `df.select(col("name"), col("age"))` you will get a new `DataFrame` containing only the desired columns.